# Sci-fi movie where an exploring spaceship gets stuck in a planet's atmosphere

Tags: story-identification, movie

Around 2005-06 I saw around 15 minutes of a live-action movie on my TV.

Some astronauts travelling in their spaceship try to land their ship on a planet. The plot twist was, after entering that planet's atmosphere their ship is (literally) stuck in the atmosphere. Where the planet's atmosphere should be gassy or windy, instead it's comprised of floating meteors in the atmosphere.

Comment: @steveSarsawa: I have edited the language of your question for greater clarity. I hope you approve.

Comment: @steveSarsawa: Did the planet actually turn out to have rocks floating in the atmosphere?

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen thank's for ur efforts behind my post, actually i've seen 15-16 minutes during i'm getting ready for my school. That's the reason i don't know more

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Not a great match but The Doctor who movie (2010) A Christmas Carol had a spaceship trapped in an atmosphere https://youtu.be/l_XpuaIwod4

Comment: @lucasbachmann I was talking about 2005-06 :(

Answer (score 3):

There seems an outside chance that this could be the Voyager Episode [Blink of an Eye](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Blink_of_an_Eye_(episode)) S06E12.

While the OP has specified a live-action movie on TV, they've also said they only saw 15 minutes, which leaves open the possibility of mistaking a TV show for a lower budget movie. This episode was originally broadcast in 2000, Voyager would probably have been on permanent loops on various TV channels by 2005/06

The cold opening has the ship and crew being pulled into orbit of a new planet and rooted in the sky as a permanent fixture.

> The USS Voyager approaches a planet rotating 58 times per minute and, while investigating, the ship enters a gravimetric gradient pulling it into a geosynchronous orbit in which the crew becomes trapped. On the planet, a native is then seen preparing an altar. Just then, an earthquake occurs, and the native sees a new star in the sky, which is Voyager.

Later on, we have some classic astronaut suited types getting more closely involved with the crew before saving their ass.

[image: Astronaut!]

Comment: Can u please specify the episode number if possible!, bcz there're several episodes in the list and hard to find all of them so if specific episode number got then easy to find full episode and watch it :)

Comment: @steveSarsawa good call. Done.

Comment: I've seen your mentioned episode, thank for suggestion it was really enjoying. But still this is not that, For what I was looking for